# Getting interface not assignable to parameter while using useState

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I am getting this error `Argument of type 'MyInterface[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<MyInterface | null>.` I am unsure of what to do here. I feel like I have run into this before, but unsure of what I did to resolve it. Here is what I have:

```
interface MyInterface {
  email: string;
  name: string;
}

const [selection, setSelection] = useState<MyInterface | null>(null);

//defaultValue is being populated from a query pull and it is of type MyInterface[]

useEffect(() => {
   setSelection(defaultValue);
 }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Argument of type 'MyInterface[]'
//                -----------^^

is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<MyInterface | null>.
//                                                     ---------^^
```

See the problem now?

---

You have a state that is a `MyInterface`, but you are trying to assign an array of `MyInterface` to that state.

So you probably want to type your state to accept `MyInterface[]` instead.

```
const [selection, setSelection] = useState<MyInterface[] | null>(null);
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAogGZnoDG8AvnGVBCHAORTo42sBQPwAO3xQyXdHACyATwCSQ9CLGIecOOhA5gAGwBccVDCiCA5gG4VcAThDo9BowLM9afKhAEG4AbQxbqMYHciDBhMdD8aQIEAXTgAXmIsXHwAHmk5YVEqdC9YgB9LZC0tAD4ACgEirQBKcx4AE2otHA44Nw94RtEimAA1HC1kW0lZeUVs3L40dHJKGjKy6viS5VV9dFDw-yiyrpwe-sH0WpVaIlyToA)